# Wordpress / Woocommerce Hook into a Function

Tags: wordpress, function, hook, hook-woocommerce

I appreciate questions similar to this have been asked before but the answers I've tried aren't doing what I need.

Basically,

I have this file in the woocommerce plugin folder structure:

> wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-coupon-functions.php

Inside the file is the following function:

```
function wc_get_cart_coupon_types() {
    return (array) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon_types', array( 'fixed_cart') );
}
```

I need to override it so it returns an additional item in the array but nothing I've tried has worked. I've tried:

1. Creating the same file in my custom theme file
2. hooking the function in my functions file with the following code:

   function woocommerce_coupon_get_cart_coupon_types()
   {
       return (array) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon_types', array( 'fixed_cart', 'custom_discount' ) );
   }

   add_filter('wc_get_cart_coupon_types', 'woocommerce_coupon_get_cart_coupon_types',10, 1);

Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated, also..... I've made the change directly in the file and it definitely works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your #2 approach is sort of how to do it, but you're essentially caught in a loop situation the way you did it.

You need to do it this way:

```
function wpso59974749_woocommerce_coupon_get_cart_coupon_types( $data ) { 
    $data[ 'your_new_key_here' ] = 'your new value here';
    return $data;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_cart_coupon_types','wpso59974749_woocommerce_coupon_get_cart_coupon_types',10, 1);
```

You shouldn't add the `apply_filter` back in your function, as it would get stuck in a loop - essentially refiltering itself over and over.

I prefixed your function so if there is another `woocommerce_coupon_get_cart_coupon_types` function, it won't conflict.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion but unfortunately I'm not getting the required result. I've dropped your example code in, replaced the key/value and still nothing. It's really confusing as I'm overriding other woocommerce functions in my functions file also :-(

Comment: What happens when you do `var_dump( $data )` as the first line inside the function? I'm curious what you're returning.

Comment: I found a fix and absolutely no idea if its' the right way of doing it. Rather that overriding the function name in the original file, I've overridden the the name of the 'apply_filter' instead. It fixed my problem. So I have this instead:                                                                     `function wpso59974749_woocommerce_coupon_get_cart_coupon_types( $data ) { 
    $data['custom_discount'] = 'custom_discount';
    return $data;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_cart_coupon_types','wpso59974749_woocommerce_coupon_get_cart_coupon_types',10, 1);
`

Comment: put the wrong tag name for the filter. It's been updated. The correct one was `woocommerce_cart_coupon_types`

Comment: Yeah, your way is correct now. I fixed my answer to reflect the correct hook tag.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was trying to explain, just struggled to express it in words. Either way, thanks for your help.